# Why does my Background Image in Blogger not appar correclty in IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, background, blogger

http://ourunitedvoice.blogspot.com/

It looks GREAT in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and more. BUT when my blog is viewed in IE 8 (sadly, still common among our visitors) the background image covers only the main body of the blog and not the sides out to 962 pixels and beyond. Help!

Here is the code I currently have!

```
hhtml, body {
background: url(https://metrounitedway.org//servlet/eAndar.WebExtDocument?DocID=323435303237&ArticleID=333137) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}.content-inner {background-color:transparent !important;}
.tabs-outer,.main-outer,footer {background-color:white !important;}.header-fauxborder-left
{
    background-image:url('https://metrounitedway.org//servlet/eAndar.WebExtDocument?DocID=323435303237&ArticleID=333137');
    background-repeat:repeat;
}.body-fauxcolumn-outer {
background: url(https://metrounitedway.org//servlet/eAndar.WebExtDocument?DocID=323435343437&ArticleID=333137) fixed;
}

.body-fauxcolumn-outer div {
background: none;
}]]></b:skin>
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `background-size:cover;` http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS code may help you:

```
`@media \0screen {
img {
width: auto; /* for ie 8 */}}`
```

---